# linux mint screen freeze on Oracle VM Virtualbox

Tags: linux, linux-mint, virtualbox, gnu-screen, freeze

First of all, I am a complete beginner in Linux. I installed Oracle VM Virtualbox on Windows 10 then Linux Mint 19.3 using Cinnamon to run a postgresql server and loaded a 3 million lines database. During that process, my screen hangs on and I can only move my mouse and nothing responds, not even to open a terminal. I can't switch off my machine using ACPI signal as nothing happens when I click on it, and I don't want to switch off my machine because I am afraid to lose all my data. What I did finally is that I saved the state of my machine until I find a solution. The only other remaining solution is to switch off the machine but I will lose all my data as I always quit by saving the state of the machine. I don't know how to do it properly.. Anyone can help me with this issue it will avoid me repeating a several days work? You can see some screeshots of the Linux Mint and the log file:[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the specs of the host (RAM, CPUs)? What resources did you give the Mint guest? Please add to your question.

Comment: I have a 32GO RAM laptop and gave 16GO to VM virtualbox running with 1 CPU. Everything seemed to work normally until I opened several firefox pages on mint and ran a heavy database on sql server using a workbench as it appears on the picture. The screen blocked on "waiting for the query to complete".

Comment: How many CPU cores does your host have? Only one for the guest is not enough for what you're trying to do. Are you running the guest on an SSD?

Comment: My host has 4 cores. Yes I am running it on an SSD

Comment: Give your guest at least 2 and see if it runs any better.

Comment: how can I change my configuration without losing my data as I need to turn off the machine first? it is more about saving data ..

Comment: Do you have backups of the VM? I don't know enough about databases or exactly what you're doing to be of much help in saving your data.

Comment: Yes I saved the state of the VM and can also clone it to try some tricks